# Returning an element with a rank k in a binary tree

Tags: search, binary-tree, rank

I already implemented a method `rankOfElement(x)` in pseudocode which returns the rank for a given node x:

```
function rankofElement(x) {
    rank = 0; 
    Node temp = root;

    while (temp.key != x) {
       if (x < temp.key) {
          temp = temp.leftson
       } else if (x > temp.key) {
          rank += temp.leftson.size + 1;
          temp = temp.rightson;
       } else if (temp.key == x) {
          return rank + temp.leftson.size
       } else return "key not found"
   }
```

Now I should implement a method (`elementbyRank(k)`) in pseudocode which returns a node with a specific rank k in the context of a binary tree. Also the implementation should have maximum O(h) time where h is the height of the tree. I am struggling with that and I hope you can give me an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Making assumptions about your tree:

- node.size is the number of children nodes plus those children's sizes. A leaf node has size 0.
- The leftmost leaf element in the tree has rank 0
- By the way you defined the above `rankOfElement()`, a node's rank is equal to the size of its left child plus one.
- The `size` of a node is initialized as 0, and is incremented every time an object is inserted into the tree - thus, it is always accurate.

So,

```
function elementbyRank(k) {
    Node temp = root;
    int tempsize = 0;

    while (k != tempsize + temp.leftson.size + 1) {
        if (k < temp.leftson.size + 1) {
            temp = temp.leftson;
        } else if (k > temp.leftson.size) {
            tempsize += temp.leftson.size + 1;
            temp = temp.rightson;
        } else {
            return "rank not found";
        }
    }
    return temp;
```

This essentially does a binary search on your binary tree, except instead of using `key` as the criteria, it uses `size`. The search terminates when it reaches a node with the desired rank.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just have one more question: What do you mean with  
while (temp != tempsize + temp.leftson.size + 1) ? Because temp is a node and tempsize + temp.leftson.size + 1 is a integer value.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that should be `k` there, not `temp`. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the rank (`pos` parameter) is valid, the parameter `r` is the root, and that the number of nodes of each subtree is stored in a field called `size`, this is a version in C++/C pseudocode:

```
Node * elementbyRank(Node * r, int pos)
{
  while (pos != r->left->size)
    {
        if (pos < r->right->size)
            r = r->left;
      else
        {
          pos = pos - r->left->size + 1;
          r = r->right;
        }
    }    
  return r;
}
```

The function would return the root corresponding to the inorder position `pos`.

You could program it recursively.